# How much juice can a mango yield if run through a juicer?

Tags: measurements, juice, mango

If I know the weight of a mango, or the weight of a bowl of mangoes, is there any way to reasonably estimate what volume of juice the mango, or bowl of mangoes, will yield if run through a juicer?

Comment: Your challenge there is going to be (a) mango pits can vary in size relative to the size of the mango, and (b) some mangos are juicier than others.  I'd suspect that you could do some kind of estimation by testing water displacement, but I have no idea what the measurements would be.

Comment: **@FuzzyChef**: That's not a comment! That's an answer! (As the answer is: It's impossible to estimate without trying out 50% of the mangoes **Village** has...) ping me after answering and I'll come back and upvote.